# Align two columns of strings in pandas (merge strings recursively until match)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following pandas df

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': ["Sun", "Sea:", "SARS-COV-2", "Hong-Kong", "Fish", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN"],
                        'col2': ["Sun", "Sea", ":", "SARS", "-", "COV", "-", "2", 'Hong', '-', 'Kong', 'Fish'],
                        'col3': ["H", "Q", "S", "X", "Y", "Z", "L", "M", 'A', 'B', 'C', 'O']})
df
```

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sun | Sun | H |
| Sea: | Sea | Q |
| SARS-COV-2 | : | S |
| Hong-Kong | SARS | X |
| Fish | - | Y |
| NaN | COV | Z |
| NaN | - | L |
| NaN | 2 | M |
| NaN | Hong | A |
| NaN | - | B |
| NaN | Kong | C |
| NaN | Fish | O |

I need to align col1 and col2, just as shown in df2

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': ["Sun","Sea:", "SARS-COV-2", "Hong-Kong", "Fish"],
                        'col2': ["Sun", "Sea:", "SARS-COV-2", "Hong-Kong", "Fish"],
                        'col3': ["H", "Q", "X",  "A",'O']})
df2
```

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sun | Sun | H |
| Sea: | Sea: | Q |
| SARS-COV-2 | SARS-COV-2 | X |
| Hong-Kong | Hong-Kong | A |
| Fish | Fish | O |

This is,  I have to recursively merge the strings of col2 until there is a match with col1, while preserving the first col3 value

My initial approach was to use nested loops but it became very confusing.

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you know that col2 is properly sorted?

Comment: Also, if we’re always keeping the first value of col3, why is col2 and building up its clean version even necessary?

Comment: You are right, we could have removed col2 in df2, because the desired result is the first value of col3 for each merged token

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split `col1` by non alphanumeric character `'\W'` to get the same output as `col2`:

```
# Assume NaN is np.nan and not 'NaN' else use .replace('NaN', np.nan).dropna()
grp = (df['col1'].dropna().str.split('(\W)').explode().loc[lambda x: x != ''])

df1 = df.groupby(grp.index).agg({'col2': lambda x: ''.join(x), 'col3': 'first'})
out = pd.concat([df['col1'].dropna(), df1], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> out
         col1        col2 col3
0         Sun         Sun    H
1        Sea:        Sea:    Q
2  SARS-COV-2  SARS-COV-2    X
3   Hong-Kong   Hong-Kong    A
4        Fish        Fish    O
```